# How can I scale the labels on a coordinate plane using tkz-euclide?

Tags: scaling, coordinates, tkz-euclide

I have some code to make a coordinate plane that my students can use for graphing, but it takes up most of the page.

Working Code, but image is too large:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1in, rmargin=1in, tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in]{geometry} %1 inch margins
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % coordinate plane

\setlength{\parindent}{0in} % No indent on line returns 
\pagestyle{empty} %no page numbers

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzAxeXY
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Looks good but too big]

I've tried scaling the whole picture, but the labels don't scale. It ends up looking terrible.

Same code with scaling added, but labels look awful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1in, rmargin=1in, tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in]{geometry} %1 inch margins
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % coordinate plane

\setlength{\parindent}{0in} % No indent on line returns 
\pagestyle{empty} %no page numbers

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
        \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzAxeXY
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: good size but looks awful]

How can I scale the labels with the rest of the picture so it looks nice but fits better on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `scale` for the `tikzpicure` does not scale nodes by default. But the labels are nodes. So you have to use option `transform shape` to scale the nodes too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1in, rmargin=1in, tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in]{geometry} %1 inch margins
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % coordinate plane
\setlength{\parindent}{0in} % No indent on line returns 
\pagestyle{empty} %no page numbers
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.50,
    transform shape% <- added to scale nodes too
]
    \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, in the sense that there ought to be a tikz solution, however, one option is to use `\scalebox` from the [graphicx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package. This produces:

[image]

The full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1in, rmargin=1in, tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in]{geometry} %1 inch margins
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % coordinate plane
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in} % No indent on line returns
\pagestyle{empty} %no page numbers

\begin{document}

    \scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzAxeXY
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bobbi The standard way to thank is to up-vote helpful solutions and to give a green to the solution, if any, that best addresses your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did both, but I don't have enough reputation for my up-votes to be visible.

Comment: @Bobbi You don't need reputation to make your up-votes visible, but esdd's solution is the the "correct" answer:)